# how to read specific line and save value in a table using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have below format txt file.which is huge file.

is there a way we can read it using PowerShell and store ID, test,test1 value in a table?

Text file:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
ID : 1927
----------------------------------------------------------------


----------------------------------------------------------------
Mode="calculated"
----------------------------------------------------------------
Score test: 0.0403942318, test1 : 0.040394231826281
path: , path1: \\xyz\cbd

----------------------------------------------------------------
ID: 4653
----------------------------------------------------------------


----------------------------------------------------------------
Mode="calculated"
----------------------------------------------------------------


Score test: 0.003569656, test1 : 0.00356965601405712
path: , path1: \\xyz\cbd


----------------------------------------------------------------
ID: 5419

-------------------------
```

Comment: Did You try anything? 
Please post part of actual file. 
Try using get-content |select-string  <Regular_expression> combo

Comment: @tomek , no i haven't .sorry i am new to power shell. will check the above way.above is the part of actual file.

Comment: If you're so new to PowerShell that you don't even know where to start you need to find a tutorial first. SO is not a replacement for that, and we're also not a code-writing service.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers , sorry for that , actually i am seeking for help/direction not code.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love named capture groups:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\07\SO_50212799.ps1
$InputFile = '.\file.txt'
$NewTable = Get-Content $inputFile | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^ID[: ]+(?<ID>\d+)') { $ID = $Matches.ID }
    if ($_ -match 'test[: ]+(?<Test>[0-9\.]+).*?test1[: ]+(?<Test1>[0-9\.]+)') {
      [pscustomobject]@{
        'ID'    = $ID
        'test'  = $Matches.Test
        'test1' = $Matches.test1
      }
    }
}

$NewTable
```

Sample output

```
> Q:\Test\2018\05\07\SO_50212799.ps1

ID   test         test1
--   ----         -----
1927 0.0403942318 0.040394231826281
4653 0.003569656  0.00356965601405712
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have a large file you may want to process it line-by-line via pipeline. The general construct looks like this:

```
Get-Content $inputFile | ForEach-Object {
    # do stuff here
}
```

Use a regular expression for matching ID lines and extracting the ID:

```
if ($_ -match '^ID : (\d+)$') {
    $id = $matches[1]
    # ...
} else {
    # processing of non-ID lines goes here
}
```

Processing of a record should start when you encounter an ID line and should end when you encounter either the next ID line or the end of the file.